# Snowflake Pivot

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a 4 column table SurveyID, QuestionID, PersonID, Response that has about 300+ unique questions (QuestionId's). I would like to just break out the QuestionID's into columns to have 300+ columns.

```
with c as
(select Distinct QUESTION_ID from "SURVEY_PERSON_QUESTION_RESPONSE"
where SURVEYID = 'SURVEY1')

select * 
  from "SURVEY_PERSON_QUESTION_RESPONSE"
    pivot(max(SURVEY_ID) for QUESTION_ID in c
```

I also tried to get it to run on just a couple out of the 300+ question ID values:

```
  select * from SURVEY_PERSON_QUESTION_RESPONSE
    pivot(max(SURVEY_ID) for QUESTION_ID in ("FirstName", "LastName")
```

I get SQL compilation error on both:

> syntax error line 2 at position 68 unexpected ''

Answer (score 0):

Your first query won't work as you need to explicitly specify you column names, which you are trying in your second query.  Your second query leverages double-quotes instead of single-quotes in the values.  You are also missing an end-parenthesis.

```
select * from SURVEY_PERSON_QUESTION_RESPONSE
    pivot(max(SURVEY_ID) for QUESTION_ID in ('FirstName', 'LastName'));
```

There are some good examples in the Snowflake documentation, if you need a reference:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html#examples

Comment: applied your formatting and got: SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 14 invalid identifier 'SURVEY_ID'. 

Is it because all my columns are strings?

Comment: Is `SURVEY_ID` a column name in your table?

Comment: In your original post, you use both `SURVEYID` and `SURVEY_ID` so you need to use the correct column name.